# How to set WPF Datagrid RowHeaderWidth to Auto?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, grid, row

I have a datagrid in my application (WPF environment) to load data into it. 
Row header in my app have row number in it (just like excel).
Now my problem is when I have 99 rows, the width of row header is correct but when it is more than that rowheader width is too small and cuts the number (see the picture). I want to set rowheaderwidth to auto but there is no in-built command for that.any ideas? thanks for the help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your own DatagridRowHeaderTemplate.
See this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/62e7b57d-b83f-4d25-bdb4-89b55f383bca/

Comment: I found out what was the problem; setting width in multiple places in my code. But I really like the solution you attached and I am going to use it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to the [DataGrid.RowHeaderWidth Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowheaderwidth(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> Set this property to NaN to make the row header automatically adjust its size to fit its content.

The following works as documented.

```
<DataGrid RowHeaderWidth="NaN"/>
```